# ERROR: task `public` not found in turbo `pipeline` in "turbo.json"

Tags: next.js, e-commerce, turborepo

I tried to build my Next.js Commerce with Swell storefront integration. It uses turbo and the result of build is

> ERROR: task `public` not found in turbo `pipeline` in "turbo.json". Are you sure you added it?

I looked at configuration options of turbo documentation, but I don't have any idea where to put `public` in `turbo.json`. I tweaked around with it for a while, but no chance to fix it myself.

`/turbo.json`:

```
{
  "baseBranch": "origin/main",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**"]
    },
    "next-commerce#build": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "^build",
        "$COMMERCE_PROVIDER",
        "$BIGCOMMERCE_STOREFRONT_API_URL",
        "$NEXT_PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN",
        "$NEXT_PUBLIC_SWELL_STORE_ID"
      ],
      "outputs": [".next/**"]
    },
    "test": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": []
    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": []
    },
    "prettier-fix": {
      "outputs": []
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "start": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "types": {
      "outputs": ["dist/**/*.d.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

`/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "commerce",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "site",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build --filter=next-commerce..." ,
    "dev": "turbo run dev",
    "start": "turbo run start",
    "types": "turbo run types",
    "prettier-fix": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "turbo": "^1.2.16"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "turbo run lint"
    }
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.17"
}
```

`/site/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "next-commerce",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build public",
    "start": "next start",
    "analyze": "BUNDLE_ANALYZE=both next build",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prettier-fix": "prettier --write .",
    "find:unused": "npx next-unused"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.4.1",
    "@vercel/commerce": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-bigcommerce": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-commercejs": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-kibocommerce": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-local": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-ordercloud": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-saleor": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-shopify": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-spree": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-swell": "^0.0.1",
    "@vercel/commerce-vendure": "^0.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "keen-slider": "^6.6.3",
    "lodash.random": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "next": "^12.0.8",
    "next-themes": "^0.0.15",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "postcss-nesting": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.3.1",
    "react-merge-refs": "^1.1.0",
    "react-use-measure": "^2.1.1",
    "tabbable": "^5.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.0.8",
    "@types/body-scroll-lock": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/lodash.random": "^3.2.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.8",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.7",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "4.3.4"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint",
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ],
    "**/*.{md,mdx,json}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "next-unused": {
    "alias": {
      "@lib/*": [
        "lib/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*": [
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "@config/*": [
        "config/*"
      ],
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ]
    },
    "debug": true,
    "include": [
      "components",
      "lib",
      "pages"
    ],
    "exclude": [],
    "entrypoints": [
      "pages"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: which command did you run that threw this error?

Comment: I edited the post. I run `yarn build` to run `turbo run build --filter=next-commerce...`, since I searched around the solution and found `next build <outDir>` somewhere. And I even added `public` right after the build script, `turbo run build public`, but it still generates the error.

Comment: can you edit your post and include  the `next-commerce`'s package.json?

Comment: I did. I just cloned and deployed and got this error.

Comment: isn't this package.json you posted from the root of the project? Can you post the package.json of `next-commerce` workspace?

Comment: Oh right, it isn't. I added `/site/package.json` as well. As you see, I also put `public` to `"build": "next build"` in the `site/package.json` and I tried to deploy on Vercel again, tweaking root directory from `./` (by default) to `site`, but none worked well.